# Converting two integers into a long in PHP

Tags: php, integer, type-conversion, long-integer

I've got two integers and I need to convert them into a long. I'm totally lost on how to do this. The two integers that I need to convert are:

```
INT 1: 60850985 
INT 2: 59150141
```

I need a method that converts two integers into a long. If you can post one, that'd be great.

When I say converting to a long, I'm wondering how you would do the equivalent of (long) from java in PHP

---

Let me be completely clear here: 
I'm receiving two ints from the client, then I need to convert them to a long, then the single long is to be used again as a single int.

In essence, I need to take two ints and convert them into a single int. An example of how this is done in java would be:

```
  long $intA = (long) readInt();
  long $intB = (long) readInt();
  return ($intA << 32) + $intB;
```

Comment: I'm getting `120001126` not `60000564`. What are you trying? Could you post what you've done?

Comment: Ohh. I misread the long. I was totally wrong on what the long should be. What method did you use to convert the ints to a long?

Comment: He added them together. Please define what you mean by "convert them into a long".

Comment: I need the equivalent of casting to a long in Java. My bad for being unclear.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a long datatype

Comment: I need to be able to represent a long though. Can that be done?

Comment: @MitchellM You have a fundamental misunderstanding here. PHP is a loosely typed language with only a few primitives - integer, float, bool, string, array. An "integer" can hold the value of a "long", since they're not really the same as in Java.

Comment: Okay well. Here's my full issue: I'm reading two integer values from a stream and I need them represented as a long. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could just write a function to take two string integers and output a string answer - just do addition from the right, carry values to the next column etc, as per addition taught in school `:)`

Comment: @MitchellM The `integer` data type in PHP could more accurately be described as "whole number" (which is what an integer is in math, but I'm being broad here to keep the programming definitions out of it). Assigning a "long" value to a variable makes that variable an "integer" type, but it's perfectly capable of holding your "long" value - at least as long as your system can hold a number of that length (depending on if your system is 32 or 64-bit, and if PHP is compiled to use its full capability, that is.)

Comment: I updated my main question. Please re-read if you could.

Comment: @MitchellM, the code you posted is more reminiscent of Java-like PHP. PHP does not support explicit type declarations. As quoted from the manual `PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used. That is to say, if a string value is assigned to variable $var, $var becomes a string. If an integer value is then assigned to $var, it becomes an integer.`

I also think you should pore over the way how PHP handles types: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: I understand all of this. I'm just trying to figure out how to convert the two integers into a single variable that would represent the same thing if done in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used regular addition:

```
$int1 = 60850985;
$int2 = 59150141;
$result = $int1 + $int2;//120001126
```

Here's a quote from the PHP manual:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does
>   not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using
>   the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant
>   PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

If you want to deal with large numbers use GMP ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php ) or BCMath ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php ).

To elaborate on what AgentConundrum said, there isn't a need to cast an integer to a long in PHP. PHP is a dynamic language which means that generally, for operations on fundamental types, there is no need for casting (unless it is for some explicit purpose - i.e. a float to an integer), as PHP handles it for you.

Answer (score 3):

PHP stores numbers as integers or floats, where the size of the integer is platform dependent (but usally 32 bit, signed). If you need to represent a larger number you should use the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) functions.

Using BCM adding two numbers is like:

```
$a = '60850985';
$b = '59150141';
echo bcadd($a, $b);
```

or multiplying:

```
$a = '60850985';
$b = '59150141';
echo bcmul($a, $b);
```

EDIT:

If you want to get, how it should look as a 64-bit signed integer in 1-complement (if there is an overflow), then you have to do some manual conversion to cast the value inside the `-2^63 .. 2^63-1` range:

For nonnegative values you can for example first cast it to `0 .. 2^64-1`:

```
$long = bcmod($value, bcpow('2','64'));
```

Then if it's larger than `2^63-1` then subtract `2^63` from it, and then subtract this value from `-2^63`.

For negative values, first add `2^64`, until the value is positive, then do the above steps.

But the above steps are only needed if you want to check how the string number looks if there was an overflow. Usually you don't need this, and probably you don't even need to use BCM as your numbers will easily fit inside PHP's signed 32-bit integer datatype (for which no casting is needed, conversion is automatical):

```
$a = '123'; // $a is a string
echo $a + 1; // will write 124, $a gets converted into int
```

You can force conversion if you want though:

```
$a = $a+0;
```

or

```
$a = (int)$a;
```

EDIT 2:

You can still use BCM functions to do the math:

```
$long = bcadd($low, bcmul($high, bcpow('2','32'))) 
// this essentially means:
// $long = $low + $high * 2^32
// which is
// $long = $low + $high << 32
```

Then, if the result is larger than `2^63-1` you can do some additional BCM calculations, described above to convert the unsigned integer into a signed one.

Comment: If you know the calculation you have to write (a+(b<<32)), why not do it using BCM? Anyway, added the code to do that.